# Displaying Class Which Extends JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I'm still relatively new to Swing and GUI programming in general, so I'm probably making some very simple mistake here, but:

I have a class called `TilePanel` which extends `JScrollPane`. The purpose of this class is to contain another custom class of mine, `TileMap`, which itself extends `JPanel`. The problem I have is that the `TilePanel` never displays.

This seems exceedingly weird to me, because, before creating the `TilePanel` class,   I ran a test where I used a normal `JScrollPane`  in its place, and added the `TileMap` to it. This displayed normally for me, and I was able to successfully scroll my `TileMap`. The code in my `TilePanel` class doesn't really change much about the `JScrollPane` yet, so I can see no reason why this should not be working.

Here is the code for the `TilePanel` class:

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TilePanel extends JScrollPane
{
    TileMap map;

    public TilePanel(int rows, int cols)
    {
        super(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        map = new TileMap(rows, cols, 9, 9);
        map.addBorder(Tile.EMPTY, 9);
        this.add(map);
    }
}
```

`TileMap` uses a `GridLayout` for its default layout, if that effects anything.

From my searches both on here, and elsewhere, I have not found anyone having a similar problem, unless I'm just really bad at searching. I found a few people who had problems with adding stuff to the `JScrollPane` itself, but not anyone who had a problem displaying a class which extended `JScrollPane`.

If more information is needed, I'll be happy to add it.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem. I apparently can't use .add(JComponent component) as it overrides the Viewport. I have to use setViewportView(Jcomponent component).

Comment: Which is what I suggested in my answer. Don't create a TilePanel class and use the code I suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't extend JScrollPane, you are not adding any new functionality to the scrollpane. Just create the TileMap class and set it to the viewport of the scrollPane.

In the class where you create the TilePanel class you code should look something like:

```
//TilePanel panel= new TilePanel(); // not needed.
TileMap map = new TileMap(rows, cols, 9, 9);
map.addBorder(Tile.EMPTY, 9);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( map );
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

Comment: It doesn't add anything to JScrollPane yet, but it will. This was a problem I wanted to solve before I did start adding the extra functionality, though.

Comment: @Aargonian, you are not adding functionality to the scrollpane. You are adding components to the viewport of the scrollpane. There is no need to create a TilePanel class.

Comment: You're right, I was being rather silly doing that. I'm not sure what I was thinking.